# System Settings Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

In am unable to use some items in System Settings as displayed page is too big for Laptop 6x4 screen.How can I resize?

Comment: You can try connecting an external monitor.

Comment: Or perhaps you could try dragging the window to the very top of the screen to biggerize it and make it fill the screen.

Comment: If you can get to the Display settings you can increase the screen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to **System Settings**
2. Select **Screen Display**
3. Set the desired resolution
4. Reduce the slider in **Scale for menu and title bar**
   Hope this helps